# How to get user id from JWT token

Tags: reactjs, jwt, mern, userid

I am trying to get the user id so I can connect models in mongoose and keep track of what each user has posted. But in order to do that I need to get the user id from jwt token and I have no idea how.
This is a MERN application and I have tried to get the id in the from from react but unsuccessfully.  Here is my code:

Authentication with jwt

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const util = require("util");

const passwordHash = require("../../config/passwordHash")
//get middleware
const authenticateUser = require("../middleware/authenticateUser");
const validateBodyWith = require("../middleware/validateUserWith");

//data validators
const { loginValidator, registerValidator } = require("../validation");
//load User model
const { User } = require("../../models");

const jwtSign = util.promisify( jwt.sign );

//get currently validated user
router.post("/authenticated", authenticateUser, (req,res)=>{
  // console.log(req.user);
  res.json(req.user);
});

 //log in an existent user by signing and returning a secure json web token
 // for the client application to store and include with requests

router.post("/login", validateBodyWith(loginValidator), async(req,res)=>{
 
  const {email,password} = req.body;
  console.log(req.body);

  try{
    const user = 
      await User
      .findOne({email})
      // .populate('records');
    if(!user){
      //user not found by email
      return res.status(404).json({default:"your email or password is invalid"})
    }
  
    const {
      password: encryptedPassword,
      // User object without the password
      ...secureUser
    } = user._doc;
    console.log("user----:",secureUser)

    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare( password, encryptedPassword );
    
    if( !isMatch ) {
      // User's password is invalid.
      return res.status(404).json({ default: "Email or password is invalid." });
    }

    const payload = {
      id:secureUser._id,
      email:secureUser.email
    };
    console.log(payload);
    //create a signed web token to send back to the client for reauthentication
    const token =  await jwtSign(
      payload,
      process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      {
        expiresIn:31556926 //one year in seconds
      }
    );

    return res.json({
      sucess:true,
      token: "Bearer " + token,
      user:secureUser
    })
  }catch(err){

    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({default:"something went wrong trying to log in "})
  }

});

// creates a new user for authentication 

router.post("/register", validateBodyWith(registerValidator), async(req,res)=>{
  console.log(req.body)
  try{
    const { name, email, password } = req.body;

    const user = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (user) {
      // User already exists error.
      return res.status(400).json({ email: "Email already exists." });
    }

    const newUser = new User({
      name,
      email,
      password: await passwordHash( password )
    });

    await newUser.save();

    const {
      password: encryptedPassword,
      // User object without the password
      ...secureUser
    } = newUser._doc;

    res.json( secureUser );

  }catch(err){
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({ default: "Something went wrong creating your account." });

  }

});
module.exports = router;
```

Middleware :

```
const passport = require('passport');

const authenticateUser = passport.authenticate('jwt',{session:false});

module.exports = authenticateUser;
```

```
const mapValidationErrors = errors => errors.reduce( (errors, {field, message}) => ({ ...errors, [field]: message }), {} );

const validateBodyWith = validator => ( req, res, next ) => {

    const result = validator( req.body );

    // Body data valid! Continue to the next step...
    if( true === result ) return next();

    // Validation failed! Send and error response.
    res.status(400).json( mapValidationErrors(result) );

}

module.exports = validateBodyWith;
```

```
const validatorFactory = require("./validatorFactory");

const loginValidator = validatorFactory({
  email: { type: "email" },
  password: { type: "string", empty: false }
});

module.exports = loginValidator;
```

```
const validatorFactory = require("./validatorFactory");

const registerValidator = validatorFactory({
  name:{type:"string", empty:false},
  email: { type: "email" },
  password: { type: "string", empty: false }
  
});

module.exports = registerValidator;
```

```
const Validator = require("fastest-validator");
const  { ObjectID } = require("mongodb");

const v = new Validator({
  defaults: {
      objectID: {
          ObjectID
      }
  }
});

const validatorFactory = schema => v.compile({
  $$strict: "remove",
  ...schema
});

module.exports = validatorFactory;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use passport, then your user's id can be retrieved from `req.user.id`

I will recommend you to do a detail reading @ http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-jwt/ since you can either pass the JWT code from Client Side to Server Side from Authorization header, or cookie.

> #### Include the JWT in requests
>
> The strategy will first check the request
> for the standard Authorization header. If this header is present and
> the scheme matches options.authScheme or 'JWT' if no auth scheme was
> specified then the token will be retrieved from it. e.g.
>
> Authorization: JWT JSON_WEB_TOKEN_STRING..... If the authorization
> header with the expected scheme is not found, the request body will be
> checked for a field matching either options.tokenBodyField or
> auth_token if the option was not specified.
>
> Finally, the URL query parameters will be checked for a field matching
> either options.tokenQueryParameterName or auth_token if the option was
> not specified.